# How to match this Data in Oracle database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have two tables table1 and table2 having country description column `Country_name` in Oracle database

Table1 has `country_name` data like

```
INDIA
AUSTRALIA
JAPAN
USA
```

Table2 has `country_name` data like

```
India
Australia
Japan
USA (United State of America)
```

Now I want to join data of country_name in both tables and it should return all 4 rows in my result.

I have tried below query but its returning 3 rows only, not matching 4th record.

```
select distinct A.COUNTRY_NAME
from TABLE1 A,
     TABLE2 B 
where upper(trim(A.COUNTRY_NAME)) = upper(trim(B.COUNTRY_NAME));
```

Please provide your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you expect to join the valu `USA` against `USA (United State of America)`? Oracle does not include magic tricks. You need to specify clear rules on how do you want to perform the join.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What if table1 contains USA (United State of America), and table 2 contains USA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test for the uppercase version of names in table 2 starting with the same name as in table 1. I do not use DISTINCT since it is not possible to determine which one is right if duplicate entries would be found in table 2

```
SELECT a.country_name
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.country_name LIKE UPPER(b.country_name) || '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like operator

```
select distinct A.COUNTRY_NAME from TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B 
where  upper(trim(B.COUNTRY_NAME)) LIKE '%' || upper(trim(A.COUNTRY_NAME))  || '%'
```